# Javascript match() and invalid quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a problem with using this regular expression in javascript:

```
(?<= Received: )(.*?)(?=; )
```

What I am trying is to match everythig between two strings, in this case between "Received: " and "; ".

Here is my code:

```
var someString = "BlaBlaBla Received: blablabla; BlaBlaBla"

var receivedString = someString.match(/(?<= Received: )(.*?)(?=; )/);
```

But for the second line, I am getting an error in firebug:

```
Error: invalid quantifier
Source Code:
  var receivedDateString = dates.match(/(?<= Received: )(.*?)(?=; ));
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript does not support lookbehind assertions: `(?<= Received: )` is not a valid construct. That appears to be the source of your error.

You'll need to integrate the lookbehind into your match:

```
someString.match(/ Received: ([^;]*)/);
```

With the `[^;]*`, you don't even need the lookahead any more.

If you need to access the contents of the first capturing group directly, you could try this:

```
var receivedDateString = / Received: ([^;]*)/.exec(someString)[1]
```

Note that this assumes that there will be a match (if no `Received:` is found in the string, the indexing operation would fail).

Comment: Thank you @Tim, do you know how can I using something else to get the same result?

Comment: Great, I have it now. Thank you so so much. A real professionnal.

Answer (score 1):

Constructs like `?<=` are not supported by javascript. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a llok on that. If you can give me a solution on how to avoid using this and have the same result, I would be great.